# How to convert JUCE string to STD::string

Tags: c++, juce

Hello is there any way to convert a JUCE string to a std::string? I cannot seem to figure out how to do it in any way.

```
string GetGate() { return (to_string(Gate.char)); };
juce::String Gate = "A1";
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems pretty simple:

```
Gate.toStdString()
```

[String::toStdString](https://docs.juce.com/master/classString.html#a68a734d49f85a201a4af0e44161c0f55)

Comment: This is the updated link to the documentation (2022):
https://docs.juce.com/master/classString.html#a68a734d49f85a201a4af0e44161c0f55
Suggested edit queue is full.

Comment: What this method does to special characters of utf8, utf16, etc? Would it be more in bytes? How it behave with wchar_t on windows? I would expect more info in an answer. Documentation also suggest nothing about conversion for internal format. Please add more info!

Comment: @SolomidHero I have no knowledge of JUCE and have never encountered it outside this question, I just googled the documentation. Looks like it's utf-8 though: https://github.com/juce-framework/JUCE/blob/69795dc8e589a9eb5df251b6dd994859bf7b3fab/modules/juce_core/text/juce_String.cpp#L2086

Answer (score 0):

According to the JUCE manual, there is the method `std::string juce::String::toStdString() const`.